# Integer range in Flask REST API using SQLAlchemy

Tags: rest, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I am creating a REST API using Flask, SQLAlchemy, and Marshmallow. I have defined my Product Model in `app.py` as:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
import os

# Initialize App
app = Flask(__name__)
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Database Setup
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'db.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
# Init db
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
# Init marshmallow
ma = Marshmallow(app)


# Product Class/Model
class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer)
    qty = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, price, qty):
        self.price = price
        self.qty = qty


# Product Schema
class ProductSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'price', 'qty')


# Init Schema
product_schema = ProductSchema()
products_schema = ProductSchema(many=True)


# Create Product
@app.route('/product', methods=['POST'])
def add_product():
    price = request.json['price']
    qty = request.json['qty']

    new_product = Product(price, qty)

    db.session.add(new_product)
    db.session.commit()

    return product_schema.jsonify(new_product)

# Run the Server
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I have to perform the following logic:

1. Setting price value between `0 - 100`
2. Setting qty value between `0 - 100`

If success `return 200`, if anything wrong `return 500`.

I am not able to set Integer value between the given range by `db.Integer([0, 100])` as its giving me error:

```
TypeError: Integer() takes no arguments
```

How do I implement the above logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I've misunderstood the question and made a new function.

```
def ExpectedRange(var1):
    return 200 if var1 in range(0,100) else 500

# Create Product
@app.route('/product', methods=['POST'])
def add_product():
    price = request.json['price']
    qty = request.json['qty']

    if ExpectedRange(price) and ExpectedRange(qty) == 200:
        new_product = Product(price, qty)

        db.session.add(new_product)
        db.session.commit()

        return product_schema.jsonify(new_product)
    #else:
        # Show error. I recommend you using the method 'flash' in flask.
```

I think the problem with your code by using `db.Integer([0, 100])` as a way to find the value between 0 and 100, instead, what you should be doing is by using range with the help of a method called `randrange` from the library `random`. With all due respect, I actually don't know what you are trying to accomplish, if I am wrong, please correct me in the comments and I'll correct my post.

What I recommend you doing is to not set the price and qty in the model class, but rather, in an entirely different function and using your model class to create the elements within your database. For example:

```
from random import randrange

class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer)
    qty = db.Column(db.Integer)

def ProductRange(range1, range2):
    return randrange(range1, range2)

print(ProductRange(1,100))
```

What the function `ProductRange` will do is to choose the range between the variable `range1` and `range2`. As for returning `200` and `500`, I am not sure what you could use with this value, but I recommend doing boolean. If it is needed, `200` and `500` is simply a constant, and you could easily implement it via putting it in a function rather than using the returned value to calculate things. So, how would you use the `ProductRange` function? Just follow the code below.

```
from random import randrange

class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_name = db.Column(db.String) # Ignore this line, this just for the /addpost route to get the method POST
    price = db.Column(db.Integer)
    qty = db.Column(db.Integer)

def ProductRange(range1, range2):
    return randrange(range1, range2)

# This route is just an example of how you would use the function ProductRange
@app.route('/addpost', methods=['POST'])
def addpost():
    product_name = request.form['product_name']
    price = ProductRange(1,100)
    qty = ProductRange(1,100)
    post = Product[product_name=product_name, price=price, qty=qty]

    db.session.add(post)
    db.session.commit()

    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

If it doesn't work, please comment down below for me to help you further with this question of yours. I wish you good luck.

Comment: Hey! I've edited my code and added a POST method. My question is how do I make `price` and `qty` to only expect Integer between `0 - 100`. And if any wrong input it throws response `500` otherwise `200`. Can you please edit my code (POST method) with similar functionality, or am I doing anything incorrectly?

Comment: Oh, so what you're saying is you want a logic that expects a variable with the integer between 0 and 100, my apologies mate.

Comment: Here's a simple code to do that:
`def ExpectedRange(var1):
    return True if var1 in range(0,100) else False

print(ExpectedRange(101))`

Comment: Or make an if statement that of a function that returns 200 if it's in the range of 0 and 100 else return 500, here's a single line if statement. Note, put this in a function: `return 200 if var1 in range(0,100) else 500` Here's the full code `def ExpectedRange(var1):
    return 200 if var1 in range(0,100) else 500

print(ExpectedRange(101))`

Comment: I am having a problem with implementing what you've suggested. Can you please edit your answer and show me the exact implementation with my code so that I can send the post request with the given logic. I will be happy to accept your answer.

Comment: I've added the new edited answer if you can see above. I've made a function called `ExpectedRange` under the criteria of your logic, which is to determine whether qty and price is within 0-100. You can use the function in the context of an if condition by `if ExpectedRange(qty) and ExpectedRange(price) == 200: *your code*`. If you can provide more context to how you want to use this logic, that is much appreciated. Otherwise, if this answer doesn't help you, I am very sorry.

Comment: Let me understand what you are trying to do. The only POST method you are using is the `/product` route. And in that function, that's where you want to use the function? yes? I am assuming that whatever data that passes through that function, it should return 200. As an example, what I'll be implementing your code is simple. I'll be using my function to your code to find whether the data that went through returns a 200, if it does, it will add a new product based on that data and commits.

Answer (score 0):

since you have installed marshmallow, install the marmallow-sqlalchemy and use SQLAlchemyAutoSchema feature which will allow to you to refer directly to the model and create an instance after successful load of the json object sent in request body, plus you can define your own constraints in the schema class. the marshmallow conf. will look like:

```
from marshmallow import ValidationError, fields
from  marshmallow.validate import Range
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyAutoSchema


ma = Marshmallow(app)

# to return marshmallow parsing error
@app.errorhandler(ValidationError)
def handle_marshmallow_validation(err):
    print(err)
    return jsonify(err.messages), 400
    
# Product Schema
class ProductSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    id = fields.Integer(required=False)
    price = fields.Integer(required=True, validate=[Range(max=100, error="Value must be 100 or less")])
    qty = fields.Integer(required=True, validate=[Range(max=100, error="Value must be 100 or less")])

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        load_instance = True
```

now the ressource will look like:

```
# Create Product
@app.route('/product', methods=['POST'])
def add_product():
    # here we can check the payload validity, parse it and transform it directly to instance
    product_json = request.get_json()
    new_product = product_schema.load(product_json)

    db.session.add(new_product)
    db.session.commit()
    return product_schema.dump(new_product)
```

now if you sent value outside the range you will receive response like this

```
{
    "price": [
        "Value must be 100 or less"
    ],
    "qty": [
        "Value must be 100 or less"
    ]
}
```